# Create executable jar with maven where libraries can be replaced

Tags: java, maven, jar, libraries

Is it possible to create an executable jar with maven where it is possible to replace a particular library with a newer version of the library without creating a new executable jar?

Comment: You could keep the libraries in a folder `lib` in the application directory, have as class path not the single jars with version number, but the directory lib. (Removing the version numbers of the jars is a bit unverifiable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should define a [`provided` dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) such as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
  <version>[1.0,)</version>
  <type>bar</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And make sure the dependency is available on your application classpath when running. For example using java command to run an executable jar:

```
java -jar MyExecutableJar.jar -cp /path/to/my/library.jar
```

You can then build your executable jar and run it. Not there are several shortcoming using this method:

- Your will have to make sure your library is on the classpath when you'll execute your jar
- Maven won't be able to know which version of the dependency to use, making your build less reproducible.
- Maven requires each dependency to have a version. In my example I used `[1.0,)` to tell Maven I needed version 1.x or greater, you can adapt for your context.
- If your library's API changes in a way that is not compatible with your current JAR, you will have no choice but to re-compile your jar

That being said, I don't know why you want to make a JAR with such conditions, but chances are you'll be better of rebuilding your JAR each time you need a newer version rather than keeping it, or change your dependency and project architecture. Doing this is against best practices and Maven design.

If you provide a little more context I'll try and explain more.

Comment: Me and my colleague (different company) work on different parts of an application. I am working on the GUI and he is improving the library which he's building for the application. He asked for it so he can test the application with his changes without always creating a new jar that I have to send him.